# Swift Switch String Return

Tags: swift, switch-statement, return

Hello I have a simple switch case statement and it has an error "Missing return in a function expected to return 'String'"

All I can see is that I am returning everything. There is no if statements so it can't be a missing return.

```
enum Sign { case rock, paper, scissors }

func detectWinner(player: Sign, bot: Sign) -> String{
    switch player{
    case .rock:
        switch(bot){
        case .rock: return "You Tied"
        case .paper: return "You Lost"
        case .scissors: return "You Won"
        }
    case .paper:
        switch(bot){
            case .rock: return "You Won"
            case .paper: return "You Tied"
            case .scissors: return "You Lost"
        }
    case .scissors:
        switch(bot){
            case .rock: return "You Lost"
            case .paper: return "You Won"
            case .scissors: return "You Tied"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's odd, it compiles fine for me `Apple Swift version 4.0.3 (swiftlang-900.0.74.1 clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9`

Comment: The code is supposed to compile without error. Try to clean the project.

Comment: hmm, I copy your code and don't see error

Comment: Does the function work as expected if you return a string  “End” after of the switch a statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode was being weird. A program shutdown fix this weird bug.

Answer (score 8):

As others have said, your code should compile since you handle all of your switch statements exhaustively. Try cleaning and rebuilding.

As an aside, this seems like a good use of a switch statement with a tuple:

```
enum Sign { case rock, paper, scissors }

func detectWinner(player: Sign, bot: Sign) -> String{
    switch (player, bot){
    case (.rock, .rock): return "You Tied"
    case (.rock, .paper): return "You Lost"
    case (.rock, .scissors): return "You Won"

    case (.paper, .rock): return "You Won"
    case (.paper, .paper): return "You Tied"
    case (.paper, .scissors): return "You Lost"

    case (.scissors, .rock): return "You Lost"
    case (.scissors, .paper): return "You Won"
    case (.scissors, .scissors): return "You Tied"
    }
}
```

That seems easier to read and maintain than your nested switch statements. (And it built for me, at least in a Playground)